# Firefox won't allow me to post a form with cross origin image

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, cors, fetch

On my webpage I have a drag & drop image field that will be posted to my backend along with other form data. (copy-pasting images also works) However, here is the summary of my problem with some examples:

- Chrome: Image copied from desktop, **works.**
- Chrome: Image copied from any other website, lets say from Google images, **works.**
- Firefox: Image copied from desktop, **works.**
- Firefox, Image copied from any other website, lets say from Google images, **DOESN'T WORK.**

If I exclude the image from my form data, then it works in Firefox aswell.

With the image, on my backend I don't even see my "Request received" log. In the network tab if I investigate the request, headers and payload looks empty. Infact, everything looks empty and it doesn't trigger anything on my backend.

Another weird thing is, I have a similar function in another component but there I can post the cross origin image via firefox, I have no problem. But in this specific React component I'm having this problem. When I compare the posted files on console they are literally same. I know it looks like too much information but right now I can't decide what is causing this issue, I already did so many checks and can't figure out what is causing this.

And finally,
If the CORS is the problem, how come I can post the exact same cross origin image in another page on this React app?
If its something related to React/my code, how come it works perfectly on Chrome and not on Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example. From testing (in Firefox only) I can see that the [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) function will not return the blob in the response when I drag an image from some random website. Like you suggest this is probably due to CORS issues. Apparently the following example with the [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) works fine.

I don't know if you are using some JavaScript library? Maybe the library makes use of the fetch API.

```js
const form = document.forms.form01;

form.addEventListener('dragover', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
});

form.addEventListener('drop', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!e.dataTransfer.files.length) {
    let url = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener('load', e => {
      let file = new File([e.target.response], "img.jpg", {
        type: xhr.response.type
      });
      let transfer = new DataTransfer();
      transfer.items.add(file);
      form.img.files = transfer.files;
    });
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.send();
  } else {
    form.img.files = e.dataTransfer.files;
  }
});

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  //e.preventDefault();
  //let data = new FormData(e.target);
  //console.log([...data]);
});
```

```html
<form name="form01" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" accept="image/jpeg, image/png" name="img" />
  <div>Drop here</div>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I have a similar component where I'm dropping a cross origin image, and it just works fine, even on firefox. But somehow in this component it only works on chrome and not on firefox. So weird. So maybe CORS is not the issue.